# Delphi to Excel - Using Autofilter to delete unknown data elements

Tags: excel, delphi, com

Delphi Tokyo, Excel 2016.  By using a Delphi program, I am controlling Excel.  I am trying to delete all rows in a single sheet EXCEPT rows which have a certain value in a certain column...  For example, I have a list of businesses, where column 3 is the CITY of the business.  I need to delete all rows EXCEPT where City in ('Chicago', 'Denver', 'Columbus').   I have built and viewed an Excel Macro to see how Excel does it.... Specifically, it turns on AutoFilter, selects all values EXCEPT those cities, and then deletes.  The question I have is... how do I know what the values are in this column....?

Here is the VBA Macro code...

```
 Selection.AutoFilter
    ActiveSheet.Range("$A$1:$AF$66").AutoFilter Field:=3, Criteria1:=Array( _
        "ADDISON", "CARROLLTON", "DALLAS", "DANBURY", "EDEN PRAIRIE", "EL PASO", "ELDRIDGE", _
        "FARMERS BRANCH", "Franklin", "GEISMAR", "GRAPEVINE", "HOUSTON", "KROTZ SPRINGS", _
        "MASON CITY", "NEW BRAUNFELS", "PALO ALTO", "PLANO", "POWAY", "PURCHASE", _
        "RICHARDSON", "SAINT PAUL", "SAN ANTONIO", "SOUTHLAKE", "SUNNYVALE", "THE WOODLANDS" _
        , "ULYSSES", "WEST LAKE HLS"), Operator:=xlFilterValues   
    Rows("2:62").Select
    Selection.Delete Shift:=xlUp
    ActiveSheet.ShowAllData
```

What I need to do is to build an array of ALL cities EXCEPT the ones I want to delete. The AutoFilter knows what all unique values are...  How do I read the Autofilter, (aka the list of unique values) outside of just iterating through all rows?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The AutoFilter knows what all unique values are... How do I read the Autofilter

I don't think you can read the unique values from the AutoFilter.  If you look at the defined properties of a [filter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.office.interop.excel.autofilter.range?view=excel-pia), the unique values are not amongst them, only the cell range on which the filter operates.

Possibly the closest you could get would be to determine which rows in the filtered range are displayed on-screen and then delete the ones which aren't.  [This code](https://www.extendoffice.com/documents/excel/5215-excel-check-if-row-is-hidden.html#a1)  shows how to determine which rows are hidden.  But that seems to be rather "around the houses" to me and in any case is not what you have specifically asked.

So, you are going to have to, somehow, iterate the range yourself.

> What I need to do is to build an array of ALL cities EXCEPT the ones I want to delete.

This is actually **far** easier to do in Delphi code if you ignore the Excel AutoFilter, because it's almost trivial to find the unique cell values in an Excel range using Delphi code.

Below, I'm going to show how to do the Delphi equivalent of Coderre's formula in [this answer](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/office/forum/office_2003-excel/extract-unique-data-from-table/1ba1796a-c647-e011-9575-d8d385dcbb12). Up to you which you prefer.

Start a fresh Delphi VCL project and drop a TCheckListBox onto it.  Then compile and
execute the code below.  The code populates an Excel range with values like A, B & C
and then extracts the unique values and populates the ChecklistBox with them.  After that,
you can use the states of the individual checkboxes to process the Excel range in
any way you like.

```
vExcel,
vWorkBook,
vSheet,
vRange : OleVariant;

procedure GetUniqueValues(vRange : OleVariant; Strings : TStrings);
//  scans the Excel range represented by vRange and populates the Strings
//  variable with the unique values for in the range's Cells
var
  S : String;
  Row,
  Col : Integer;
begin
  Strings.BeginUpdate;
  Strings.Clear;
  try
    for Row := 2 to vRange.Rows.Count do begin
      for Col := 1 to vRange.Columns.Count do begin
        S := vRange.Cells[Row, Col].Value;
        if Strings.IndexOf(S) < 0 then
          Strings.Add(S);
      end;
    end;
  finally
    Strings.EndUpdate;
  end;
end;

procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
var
  i : Integer;
begin

  vExcel := CreateOleObject('Excel.Application');
  vExcel.Visible := True;

  //  Create a new workbox and populate two columns in it with random
  //  character data
  vWorkBook := vExcel.WorkBooks.Add;
  vSheet := vWorkBook.ActiveSheet;
  vSheet.Range['A1'].Value := 'City';
  for i := 1 to 20 do begin
    vSheet.Range['A' + IntToStr(1 + i)].Value := Chr(Random(3) + Ord('A'));
    vSheet.Range['B' + IntToStr(1 + i)].Value := Chr(Random(4) + Ord('A'));
  end;

  //  Extract the range A2..B21
  vRange := vSheet.Range['A2', 'B21'];

  //  Set CheckListBox1 to sort its contents
  CheckListBox1.Sorted := True;

  //  Now get the unique values
  GetUniqueValues(vRange, CheckListBox1.Items);

  //  Do whatever you like with tthe results
  for i := 0 to CheckListBox1.Items.Count - 1 do begin
    if not (CheckListBox1.State[i] = cbChecked) then
      ;
  end;
end;
```

Btw, if you look at one of the import units for Excel's automation objects, e.g. Excel2000.Pas, you'll see that the interface for IAutoFilter is defined in it, so you could conceivably access that from Delphi code if you really wanted to.

Also btw, if I were doing this myself, I'd probably do the data manipulation in SQL by accessing the spreadsheet using an ADO object like TAdoQuery, because operations like "delete all rows where some column value is not in a list of values" cries out for that sort of treatment.

Answer (score 0):

As you have been told, the unique values are not available from the `AutoFilter`, and it would have become rather complicated to mimic the functionality of the manual filtering setup, that you were attempting to achieve.

My suggestion is to use `Range.AdvancedFilter` instead of  `Range.AutoFilter`. It has a more simple way to define filtering criteria.

The macro you will call from Delphi, looks like this:

```
Public Sub UseAdvancedFilter()
    Dim MyRange As Range
    Set MyRange = Range("A1").CurrentRegion

    Range(MyRange.Address).AdvancedFilter _
        Action:=xlFilterInPlace, _
        CriteriaRange:=Range("A28:C29")

    Rows("2:" & MyRange.Rows.Count).Select
    Selection.Delete Shift:=xlUp

    ActiveSheet.ShowAllData

End Sub
```

This plays in unison with the data you have in `MyRange` and the criteria you have in `CriteriaRange`.

[image]

(I used a split view to keep the image size down. All rows between 4 and 19 have data)

You have many more columns, but we can demonstrate how the filer works with these three columns. The data range (`MyRange`) must include the headings of the data. The heading of the City field, `City` matches the headings of the `CriteriaRange`.

The `CriteriaRange` is the interesting one. We have three heading cells, all with the `City` field name. Then we have three criteria: `<>Denver`, `<>Chicago` and `<>Dallas`. Criteria that are on the same row, form a logical `AND` function between them, and the `<>` means of course `not equal to`. So, the selection criteria becomes `select records where City is not Denver and City is not Chicago and City is not Dallas`.

The result is very similar to your manual `AutoFilter` test.

[image]

If the `Public UseAdvancedFilter` procedure is placed in a public module, it can be called directly from Delphi, like:

```
Excel.Run('UseAdvancedFilter');
```

provided that Security settings don't prohibit it.

---

The above solution follows your idea of deleting all unwanted rows of data. In case you don't really want / need to delete the unwanted data, but rather hide it, for copying the wanted data, you can change the above as follows:

Change the criteria range to

```
City
Denver
Chicago
Dallas
```

Yes, that is only one column. Criteria on different rows, form a logical `OR` function between them. Thus the selection becomes

```
`select records where City is Denver OR City is Chicago OR City is Dallas`.
```

Then, we need to change what the macro does with the selection, f.ex.

```
'Selection.Delete Shift:=xlUp
Selection.Copy Destination:=Range("A40")
```

This will copy the selected records to the destination for further processing.